# ASP.NET Core 6.0: How to write the action route template for the URL like "/path:action"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

There is a rout prefix on the controller level, like

```
[Route("/api/{version:int}/pets/{petId:long}/toys/{toyId:long}")]
class PetsController: ControllerBase
```

I want to add an action to this resource - let say ":renew", i.e.
"/api/1/pets/123/toys/456:renew"

This does not seem working (404 - "/api/1/pets/123/toys/456:renew"):

```
[Route(":renew")]
```

This adds a new segment, i.e. "path/renew", not "path:renew".

```
[Route("renew")]
```

How should the route pattern look like?

ASP.NET Core 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I need to write the full route template for my action:

```
[Route("/api/{version:int}/pets/{petId:long}/toys/{toyId:long}:renew")]
```

or make prefix less specific:

```
[Route("/api/{version:int}")]
class PetsController: ControllerBase
```

and then

```
[Route("pets/{petId:long}/toys/{toyId:long}:renew")]
```

Comment: I believe the rule is: every path in a `Route` that does not start with `/` gets appended to the parent `Route`, with a `/` added in between parent path and the new path. That would explain why it worked the way it did in your original approach.